# Strict inequality in an inner product.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, inner-products

I have a convex set $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $0 \notin Y$. I fix $y_1,\dots,y_l \in Y$ 
I define $C:=C(y_1,\dots,y_l)$ as the strictly convex combinations of these $y_i$'s (strictly meaning that all $y_i$ have weight bigger than $0$).

I already know that $\exists \xi : \langle \xi , c \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in C$. Now I want to show that $\exists c \in C$ such that $\langle \xi , c \rangle > 0$.

Two remarks about this: I know that the first inequality works for $\xi$ given by $\Vert \xi \Vert =distance(0,C)$. And also that $\Vert \xi \Vert > 0$ holds. So I can make the first inequality strict and therefore also get the second.

But I want to show the strict inequality without exploiting that $\Vert \xi \Vert > 0$. I want to use the fact that $ c = \lambda_1 y_1 + \dots + \lambda_l y_l$ and at least for one of the $y_i$'s $\Vert y_i \Vert > 0$. Of course, $\Vert y_i \Vert > 0$ for all $i$, but I only one to use the weaker condition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that at least for one $y_i$, $|\langle\xi,y_i\rangle| > 0$, then due to continuity of the mapping of $t \in R^{n-1}$, $t \to t_1 \langle\xi,y_1\rangle+\cdots (1-t_1-\cdots t_{n-1})\langle\xi,y_n\rangle$ onto the convex combination there exist an open set around that extreme point for which the inequality holds, pick one suitable $c$ there. Konstructively take $t$ so that $t_i = 1$ for $i$ the coordinate with nonzero $\langle \xi, y_i\rangle$, and zero elsewere. then take $s_j = x/(n-1)$ $j \neq i$ and $s_i=-x$ then $t+s$ is a convex combination and for all small
$$
\langle \xi, \sum (t_k+s_k)y_k \rangle = \langle \xi, y_i\rangle + x \left (\left( \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k\neq i} \langle \xi, y_k\rangle \right ) - \langle \xi, y_i \rangle \right ) = \langle \xi, y_i\rangle + x C
$$ take $x = \min(1/2,\left |\frac{\langle \xi, y_i\rangle}{C}\right |/2)$ if $C$ nonzero else 1/2

Comment: Why does $\vert \langle \xi, y_i \rangle \vert > 0$ hold?

Comment: you now that there is a ball around the vector $\hat t$ for which the inequality holds for all elements in the ball because due to continuity you can find it. So go in the direction in this space that has positive coordinates and nonzero. That gives you an example that satisfy the condition. note that for the one solution wich just picks $y_i$ the inequality holds but that is for the degenerate case take the ball due to continuity around that point and go in a line from that that intersect the ball, will be a nondegenertate line segment and you have nonzero coordinates

Comment: In my opinion "you can find it" just shows that this ball exists. But constructively I need to define it explicitly.

Comment: OKej you want a construction. I added a try.